# Не работает якорь на странице Joomla 3

Tags: php, html, joomla

Создал новую статью. Поставил якорь на всплывающую форму. Но когда щелкаешь на ссылку, открывается почему-то страница "Главная".
`<a href="#popup">Нажмите</a>` - якорь
`<a href="#" id="popup"></a>` - ссылка на якорь

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вы перепутали ссылку на якорь и сам якорь и неправильно задали атрибуты. Правильно будет так:

```
<a href="#popup">Ссылка на якорь</a>    
<a name="popup">Якорь</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже не работает. По прежнему загружается "Главная".

Comment: Ну, тут есть варианты. 1) href у вас экранируется/переписывается CMS, проверьте его внимательно в браузере. 2) На ссылке висит js обработчик, который кидает на главную - это будет сложнее найти, но вы можете просто отключить js и проверить так ли это.

Comment: Проблема решается если в ссылке на якорь прописать следующим образом <a href="/index.php?id=6#top">Press!</a>, но сомневаюсь, что это верное решение. Но работает.

Comment: Хотя, может, и правильно, так как ссылка срабатывает без обновления страницы.

Comment: А когда на главную кидает в адресной строке ваш якорь остается? [http://ваша_главная/#top](http://localhost/#top) вот таким образом

Comment: да, сохраняется.

Comment: Значит скорее всего у вас в href есть что-то лишнее до знака #, проверьте

Comment: нет, лишнего ничего нет, по всей видимости это как-то связано с самой joomla. Буду вставлять ссылки на якорь, так как написал выше. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

99% что у вас вначале страницы стоит такой тэг: `<base href="site.com/" />`

Если у вас такой вариант, то решения только два 
- либо удалять тэг base.
- либо писать полный путь к странице якоря.

Comment: Сейчас нет возможности посмотреть, как только проверю отпишусь. Спасибо.